# Exporting console output to a .txt doesn't work

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I'm trying to save console output from a Script1.py to a .txt file.
However I need to run this script for several arguments, e.g. "python Script1.py 43131" where "43131" is the argument and the arguments are stored in a list (Runnummer).
What I tried to do now is to execute another script "WrapperScript1.py" to do these things for me using the typical bash export:

```
from subprocess import call
for i in range(len(Runnummer)):    
    call(["python Script1.py " + Runnummer[i] + 
          ' > ' + './test/Run' + Runnummer[i] +'.txt'])
```

This code should now execute "python Script1.py arg(i) > ./test/runarg(i).txt".
I've tried it manually for one i in the console and it works, but somehow it doesn't work if i use subprocess and loop over it.
What happens is that the code runs normally, but no console output is saved to a .txt.

I read that you can also use PIPE for this from subprocess but I didn't really get how to use it, so I tried it like above. I did also try os.system but it didn't work too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are the list of arguments determined? Is this done so in python already or could you just use the shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you know in advance the number of times you want to run the loop, you can use the shell rather than calling one python script from another:

```
for i in {0..100}; do python Script1.py $i > test/Run$i.txt; done
```

As mentioned [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376492/exporting-console-output-to-a-txt-doesnt-work/25377493?noredirect=1#comment39575876_25377493) (thanks @tripleee), the `{0..100}` range is a Bash feature, so this won't work in all shells. If your shell doesn't support brace expansions, you could use the `seq` tool `for i in $(seq 0 100)`, or failing that, a `while` loop:

```
i=0
while [ $i -le 100 ]; do
    python Script1.py $i > test/Run$i.txt
    i=$((i+1)) # POSIX compliant (thanks @chepner)
    # or, for a more vintage experience
    # i=$(expr $i + 1)
done
```

Comment: Note that the brace expression is a Bash extension. If you want or need to use `/bin/sh`, a portable solution is to use `$(seq 1 100)` instead. (The availability of `seq` isn't completely universal either, though.)

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the edit, my knowledge of shells that are older than me is quite limited :)

Comment: `expr` is unnecessary; `i=$((i+1))` is supported by POSIX.

Comment: Heh, "vintage". If you want a really obscure, steampunk (and obsolete) look in `bash`, try `i=$[i+1]` :)

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked!
And also thank you very much to the other guys who tried to help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Redirection is a shell feature. If you want to use it, the `shell` parameter needs to be set to `True`.

Furthermore, you are mixing two calling conventions. Either pass a single string for the shell to parse, or a list of parsed tokens as strings.

```
from subprocess import call
for i in range(len(Runnummer)):    
    call("python Script1.py " + Runnummer[i] + 
      ' > ' + './test/Run' + Runnummer[i] +'.txt', shell=True)
```

Since you are invoking a shell anyway, it might make more sense to do this in a shell script instead, as already suggested in [Tom's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25377493/874188).

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is `call` expect an array of arguments

The second thing is `call` don't redirect as shell so you can't use `>`

For gather output of subprocess the simpler is use `check_output` instead

```
from subprocess import check_output
Runnummer=["a","b"]
for i in range(len(Runnummer)):    
    with open('./test/Run' + Runnummer[i] +'.txt',"w") as output:
        output.write(check_output(["python","Script1.py",str(Runnummer[i])]))
```

from a pythonic style point 95% of time `range` is not needed, just iterate on list directly. So:

```
from subprocess import check_output
Runnummer=["c","d"]
for run in Runnummer:    
    with open('./test/Run' + run +'.txt',"wb") as output:
        output.write(check_output(["python","Script1.py",run]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.system` instead of `subprocess`:

```
import os
for i in range(len(Runnummer)):
    os.system('python Script1.py ' + Runnummer[i] + 
              ' > ' + './test/Run' + Runnummer[i] +'.txt')
```

Comment: Even the documentation for the `os` module recommends using `subprocess` over `os.system`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using I/O redirection in the shell, open a file for writing in Python and pass the file handle using the `stdout` argument to `call`.

```
from subprocess import call
for f in Runnummer:
    output_file = "./test/Run{0}.txt".format(f)
    with open(output_file, "w") as fh:
        call(["python", "Script1.py", f], stdout=fh)
```

Also, it's cleaner to iterate directly over your list rather than over a list of integers to use as list indices.